# Is it possible integrate the barcode reader with flex3 browser app

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, barcode

I try to integrate the barcode reader with flex3 browser application not AIR. it's possible.. or else give responsible for any components to do that.. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There is a library called zxing which was initially created for Android barcode scanning. It seems that there is a version of this lib that has been ported to ActionScript http://zxing.riaforge.org/ I think it should do what you desire. I haven't tested it though.

Comment: thank for your reply chrisdutz.. but i wan something about web app.. like http://forums.adobe.com/message/2326297#2326297

Comment: Yes ... as far as I understood it, they use the Camera (Flash can access the camera for Video Chats) and ported the algorithms to Flex ... I guess you could use the ActionScript library in Web Appliations as well as in Air Applications. As I mentioned, I haven't tried it though.

Comment: I just finished an application working with a Honeywell BlueTooth barcode scanner. Integrating this into any application (Webapp or installed application) is really easy, because these scanners act as alternate keyboards. So any Text-Field can be used for scanner input.